# Use php Get links with attribute from a html file

Tags: php, html

Here is my HTML

```
<a href="wateva" title="here she goes">  home </a>
<a href="wateva" title="coming he said"> home </a>
<a href="wateva" title=""> home </a>
```

And Php

Am trying to get all a tags with attribute "title" but it dosnt work, this is what i have tried.

```
$html = file_get_contents('home.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link)
{
   if ($link->getAttribute('name') == "title")
   {
      echo $link->getAttribute('href'). ' ';
      echo $link->nodeValue. '<p>';
   }

}
```

but it shows a blank Data. how to i fix it, need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAttribute` extracts the value of a named attribute, e.g.:

```
<a href="foo.html" name="bar">

$node->getAttribute('href'); // returns "foo.html"
```

You want

```
$node->hasAttribute('title');
```

e.g.

```
<a href="foo.html">             $node->hasAttribute('name') -> false
<a href="foo.html" name="foo">  $node->hasAttribute('name') -> true
```